# rosparam set not working

Tags: rosparam, joystick, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wanted to change the port for joystick driver from `/dev/input/js0` to `/dev/input/js1` using `rosparam` command.

`rosparam set /joy_node/input "/dev/input/js1"`

But after reboot, it changed back to `js0`. Any idea on why `rosparam` command does not permanently change the port?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281667/rosparam-set-not-working/) by [chanhyeoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/29607/chanhyeoni/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2018-02-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First of all, how you're the first value is being set isn't disclosed in your question.

Second of all, according to a question that was answered about 2 hours ago (#q281646) parameters are not stored anywhere. Once `rosmaster` is shut down all of the parameters are gone. You have to reset the parameters every time you start `rosmaster`.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0